# Javascript show PNG image

Tags: javascript

I found this script online. ITs almost what I need. Take a look:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    imageArray = new Array("NOimglink", "imglink", "imglink", "imglink");
    altArray = new Array("", "Red Star", "Yellow Star", "Pink Star");

    function show() {
        var Index = document.menuForm.select1.options[document.menuForm.select1.selectedIndex].value;
        var text = document.getElementById('select1').options[document.getElementById('select1').selectedIndex].text;
        document.testStar.src = imageArray[Index];
        document.testStar.alt = altArray[Index];
        document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = document.getElementById("select1").value;
    }
</script>
<div id="item"></div>
<form action="../action/return.html" method="post" id="menuForm" name="menuForm">
    <select id="select1" onchange="show()" name="select1">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose a color</option>
        <option value="1">Red Star</option>
        <option value="2">Yellow Star</option>
        <option value="3">Pink Star</option>
    </select>
    <img id="testStar" height="35" alt="red star" src="" width="35" border="0" name="testStar">
```

Anyways, is there any other way than using all the array lines? The imageArray and altArray? I have over 50 select options but the array is too much. Any easier way?

Comment: Please show your HTML as well. Certainly there are other ways to do (basically) everything - What isn't working with this way? What exactly is the goal here, just to swap images?

Comment: *but the array is too much* Why? Is it too big? Can you make it dynamically using your server software (PHP/ASP) instead?

Comment: I added it. The problem is. When I select an option, it shows an image. I dont want the ARRAY in javascript. I want the image to lead to something else. ETC: IN PHP Version: $blabla = "justadomain.com/image/icons/$ID.png"; the $ID would be the value of the option

Comment: And how is this specific to PNG images?

Comment: IT shows PNG images when you CLICK on an option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Don't use `innerHTML`, it's a proprietary Microsoft JScript method. No, because some low-brow decided to grandfather it in to a standard does not mean anyone should use it. XHTML and even regular HTML is not text, it's syntax. So when you later reference an element it may or may not be there because you may be referencing the DOM or you may be referencing nothing because what you thought was code was dumped as a bunch of text.

2.) Revised after you clarified your question.

Save as **example.xhtml** and make sure that you are using images with those variable names or you change the variable names in the code to the names of the images you are testing with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Dynamic JavaScript Image Generation</title>
<script type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function change_image()
{
 var se = document.getElementById('select_image');
 var img_src = se.options[se.selectedIndex].value;
 var img_alt = se.options[se.selectedIndex].text;
 var img = document.getElementById('img_target');
 img.alt=img_alt;
 img.src=img_alt+'.png';
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="get">
<fieldset>
<label for="select_image">Select an Image</label>
<select id="select_image" onchange="change_image();">
<option value="img0">Image 0</option>
<option value="img1">Image 1</option>
<option value="img2">Image 2</option>
<option value="img3">Image 3</option>
<option value="img4">Image 4</option>
<option value="img5">Image 5</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
</form>

<div><img alt="" id="img_target" src="img0.png" /></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not what i needed

Comment: Then you need to clarify further, if you don't ask a specific question you're not going to get a specific answer. "This is not what i needed" is NOT how you respond to people trying to help you.

Comment: I added it. The problem is. When I select an option, it shows an image. I dont want the ARRAY in javascript. I want the image to lead to something else. ETC: IN PHP Version: $blabla = "justadomain.com/image/icons/$ID.png"; the $ID would be the value of the option

Comment: Revised, this seems more like what you want.

Comment: The DOM is awful (why do you think jQuery even exists), and in a lot of cases using `innerHTML` is just far simpler and shouldn't introduce any of the bugs you describe. As it turns out, innerHTML is also much faster than DOM manipulation because of how well optimized browser implementations are. I'd also use HTML5 instead of XHTML (though that's a matter of opinion), but I'm definitely a bit skeptical of most everything you said in this answer.

Comment: @JakeKing jQuery is a 70KB plague that turns 2KB of useful text on a web page in to a half-megabyte nightmare that sets off everyone complaining about how much memory browsers use because people can't program REAL code. If you don't like XML don't use it. The OP says this does what they need, great! With XHTML the whole page will break on an error and that is what software should do: NOT work when broken. One guy spent three days trying to figure out that: he was missing a quote, I recover in seconds. Whats YOUR justification for text/html because to me the web is not plain/text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid all arrays, you need to modify your HTML a bit. The array serves as a key-val lookup and without that you need to set the val in the previous val spot. That is to say, make your `option value`s equal to the image src as so:

```
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose a color</option>
<option value="imgLink.png">Red Star</option>
<option value="imgLink2.png">Yellow Star</option>
<option value="img3.jpg">Pink Star</option>
```

Now it's a simple matter of setting the `option value` to the new src, and using the `option  text` as the alt text.

```
function show() {
    var elemSel = document.getElementById('select1'),
        testStar = document.getElementById("testStar"),
        newSrc = elemSel.options[ elemSel.selectedIndex ].value,
        newAlt = elemSel.options[ elemSel.selectedIndex ].text;
    testStar.src = newSrc;
    testStar.alt = newAlt;
    document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = "Src: "+newSrc+"  |Alt: "+newAlt;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/JkhxP/1/

**Edit**

If you don't want the file extension in the value, just remove it:

```
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose a color</option>
<option value="imgLink">Red Star</option>
<option value="imgLink2">Yellow Star</option>
<option value="img3">Pink Star</option>
```

And if you want the full link for the new src, just add it:

```
var elemSel = document.getElementById('select1'),
    newSrc = elemSel.options[ elemSel.selectedIndex ].value;
newSrc = "example.com/img/" + newSrc + ".png";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/JkhxP/2/

Comment: This is close! I just need values to be ids and the image link to something like: "example.com/img/$id.png" etc

Comment: If you need the values to be IDs, you need an array of some sort. Unless your images are named `id1.png`, `id2.png`, and so forth.